# How to run a Python Script (On Linux) from a nodejs server (running on windows)

Tags: python, node.js, child-process

I have a nodejs server running on Windows 10. My server needs to create thumbnails of pdfs, docx, images, etc from user uploaded files. To do this, i'm using Python and a library called [preview-generator](https://github.com/algoo/preview-generator).

Normelly, I would use nodejs to spawn a child process of my python script with some arguments, and then record the output of the script.

Unfortunately, after testing, I realized this library only works on Linux, and I cannot find any suitable replacements.

Therefore, I'm looking for a way to run my python script on Linux and have it communicate with the nodejs server, which is on Windows.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't run your Node.js system on Linux? You'd probably need some type of system on your linux system to talk back and forth to the Windows system. Which is adding a LOT more complexity than seems needed.

Comment: @CharlieFish This is just a school project and I already setup databases so transferring that all to linux would take too much time. Otherwise, I would've done that

Comment: Got it. Yeah there isn't really an easy way to do this. For a quick solution if I were you, I'd probably spin up a Node.js web server or something on that Linux machine, and make requests to that from the Windows Node.js script. I'm sure there is a better way than an HTTP web server for what you want, but it should get the job done.

Comment: Another option MIGHT be to use something like Docker, and spin up a Docker container or something with a Linux machine with it on your Windows thing. Then figure out a way to expose your database to that, and run everything within Docker. But there are a few things about that that I can't picture how it'd work off the top of my head.

Comment: @CharlieFish Ok thanks for the suggestions. I might see about trying to use Docker.  I also just remembered about Windows Subsystem for Linux, so I might use that, if its the best option.